# How to remove the specific xml element from xml by SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a xml text like below

```
<services> 
  <service class="DataBuffer.Modules.Contraparty.ContrapartyService, DataBuffer.Modules.Contraparty"> 
      <host maxMessageSize="104857600">
      </host> 
  </service> 
  <service class="DataBuffer.Modules.Goods.GoodsService, DataBuffer.Modules.Goods"> 
      <host maxMessageSize="104857600">
      </host>
   </service> 
   <...other service element....>
</services>
```

I am declaring it in the SQL

```
DECLARE @doc varchar(1000);   
SET @doc ='  
<services> 
  <service class="DataBuffer.Modules.Contraparty.ContrapartyService, DataBuffer.Modules.Contraparty"> 
     <host maxMessageSize="104857600">
     </host> 
  </service> 
  <service class="DataBuffer.Modules.Goods.GoodsService, DataBuffer.Modules.Goods"> 
     <host maxMessageSize="104857600">
     </host>
  </service> 
</services>;'
```

I need to remove the `service` XML element that has a `class` attribute whose value is

```
DataBuffer.Modules.Contraparty.ContrapartyService, DataBuffer.Modules.Contraparty
```

How do I remove this element from raw xml text by SQL? Is it possible?

Comment: Tag the question with the RDBMS you're using. I'm *guessing* it's SQL Server, but you never know. (Also, the XML in your SQL isn't valid.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert you're right. I have changed a tag from sql to SQL Server.

Comment: *Must* the transformation happen in T-SQL, or can you use an external tool (for example a script) to connect to the database and modify the XML? Also, use the XML datatype, not VARCHAR, to store XML data.

Comment: The transformation must be executed only in T-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DELETE (XML DML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/delete-xml-dml?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @doc xml='<services> 
  <service class="DataBuffer.Modules.Contraparty.ContrapartyService, DataBuffer.Modules.Contraparty"> 
     <host maxMessageSize="104857600">
     </host> 
  </service> 
  <service class="DataBuffer.Modules.Goods.GoodsService, DataBuffer.Modules.Goods"> 
     <host maxMessageSize="104857600">
     </host>
  </service> 
</services>';

SET @doc.modify('delete //service[@class="DataBuffer.Modules.Contraparty.ContrapartyService, DataBuffer.Modules.Contraparty"]')
```